# cannot subclass the final class Subject Interface

Tags: java

```
import javax.security.auth.Subject;

abstract class Department extends Subject{
    String name;


}
```

I have this piece of code. Sadly this throws the following error: `The type Department cannot subclass the final class Subject`

I was reading the documentation: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/security/auth/Subject.html but there is nothing much on how to use it(a specific use case).

Does anyone know how you can use Subject on an abstract Class (it has to be extended by an abstract class) ?

Edit: [image]

Edit 2: Error Using Implements:

```
The type Subject cannot be a superinterface of Department; a superinterface must be an interface
```

Comment: You can't derive a class from `Subject`. Maybe [delegation](http://best-practice-software-engineering.ifs.tuwien.ac.at/patterns/delegation.html) is an alternative.

Comment: What you can do is to compose a class that has a `Subject` class in it.  See this about final classes https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/IandI/final.html

Comment: Since it is a final class it cannot be extended. What were you trying to achieve from this?

Comment: This is a requirement from a homework of mine. I was given an UML and I need to have an Abstract Class department that extends subject...(we model a store, see attached image)

Comment: @MichaelButscher I tried using Implements but i get the another error (see edit)

Comment: The `Subject` in the diagram is an interface so it probably has nothing to do with the existing `Subject` **class** in the Java API.

Comment: Are you sure you aren't supposed to be creating your own `Subject` interface?

Comment: @MichaelButscher and Slaw I think you guys are very right and I am insane :D thx!

Answer (score 1):

Since `Subject` `class` is a `final` `class` you won't be able to extend it. That's the purpose of the `final` keyword. The only way I see is wrapping the class and its methods. You won't be able to use the wrapper where the final class is required, but you can implement any interfaces which are on the final class.

ex:

```
final class Foo {
    public String getSomething() {
        //
    }
}

class Bar {
    Foo foo;

    public Bar() {
        foo = new Foo();
    }

    public String getSomething() {
        foo.getSomething();
    }

    public String doSomethingElse() {
        //
    }
}
```

Not sure it would be helpful in your scenario tho.